# what is wrong with this java thread program

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this thread program in java. Can anyone shed some light? Here is the code:

```
public class Z {
    private Account account = new Account();
    private Thread[] thread = new Thread[100];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Z test = new Z();
        System.out.println("What is balance ? " + test.account.getBalance());
    }

    public Z() {
        ThreadGroup g = new ThreadGroup("group");
        boolean done = false;

        // Create and launch 100 threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            thread[i] = new Thread(g, new AddAPennyThread(), "t" + i);
            thread[i].start();
            System.out.println("depositor: " + thread[i].getName());
        }
        // Check if all the threads are finished
        while (!done)
            if (g.activeCount() == 0)
                done = true;
    }

    // A thread for adding a penny to the account
    class AddAPennyThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            account.deposit(1);
        }
    }

    // An inner class for account
    class Account {
        private int balance = 0;

        public int getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }

        public void deposit(int amount) {
            int newBalance = balance + amount;
            balance = newBalance;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs fine. It was a test question I missed and wnated to know what is actually wrong with it. Thanks!

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What doesn't it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a single bit dedicated to synchronization of 100 threads all working on exactly *one* (1!!!) piece of data.

*Anything* can happen. "Anything" includes that the code as it is works most of the time due some "coincidences":

- The task at hand is quite small. (only an add)
- The tasks are created and immediately started.
- There is a small delay between two "create+start" pair: the `System.out.println`.

This adds up to: This *might* work in *most* test-runs. But it is an incorrect and non-deterministic program.

Comment: Are you talking about "race condition?"

Comment: Thank you! You have been checked!

Answer (score 0):

```
[Tread1] int newBalance = balance + amount;
[Tread2] int newBalance = balance + amount;
[Tread1] balance = newBalance;
[Tread2] balance = newBalance;

public synchronized void deposit(int amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

`balance` should be a `private volatile int` (so that Java knows to never cache it - its value is liable to change between different thread accesses without the next thread knowing) and make `Account#deposit(int amount)` a `public synchronized void` (so that Java makes the method body a critical region and prevents simultaneous access of any of the objects it touches, ensuring the integrity of the value of `balance`).

Additionally, instantiating 100 threads yourself with `new` introduces a lot of overhead - though I appreciate this is just a toy example, a more efficient way to do this would be to use a [Java thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).